# Slow Transfer Between External Drives

Tags: macos, usb

I have two external USB drives connected to my 2012 Mac mini, and am finding transfer speeds between the two to be really slow. I need to transfer 38GB of stuff. With rsync, I was getting ~60MBps. Canceled that and moved to Finder and am getting an estimate of ~9 hours to complete the operation.

I did restart the Mac mini hoping it would improve things, but no change. Thoughts on how to improve this?

Comment: Perhaps time is being spent by Spotlight indexing 38Gb of data.

Comment: What's the make, model and type of external? HDD? SSD? Presumably USB? It's certainly true that Finder can be slow, particularly if you have lots of small files, rather than one big one.

Comment: Finder does stuff in addition to raw copy up front.  What is wrong with the rsync?

Comment: What are the drives (manufacturer/model) you've got connected? This mini is [capable of USB3](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/mac-mini-aluminum-unibody-faq/differences-between-late-2012-mac-mini-mid-2011-mac-mini-aluminum.html), but if your drives are only USB2, then that could be an indication of what's happening. Also, if you are transferring hundreds of thousands, if not millions, of files (and most files are small) that could also be a factor.

Answer (score 1):

A method I use to move large numbers of files is the Terminal `mv` or `cp` commands. The first command actually **moves** directories/files from one location to the other, the other just **copies** the directories/files. This is much quicker than Finder, which adds a tremendous amount of overhead to the process.

Secondly I strongly suggest you go to System Preferences > Spotlight, and add both external drives into the Privacy pane. This stops Spotlight from indexing the files. The drives can be removed from the pane when you're done if you want these drives indexed.

[image]

Comment: rsync works very similar to mv and cp.

Comment: I'd done this prior to starting my copy, apologies for not mentioning it. Whether Finder, rsync or cp, I'm finding my transfers unacceptably slow :/